# Dependancy problem with Owncloud installation

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

According to **Seafile** manual, I try a **Owncloud** installation on Ubuntu 14.04 with

```
apt-get install update
apt-get install owncloud
```

I have a dependency problem and I'm jam.

```
Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: owncloud : Depends: owncloud-server (= 8.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: owncloud-config-apache (= 8.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed Recommends: curl but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I need some helpful hand to guide me!

Comment: `apt-get install update apt-get install owncloud`  will not work run command `sudo apt-get update` then run `sudo apt-get install owncloud ` if not work then try to run command `sudo apt-get -f install` then try to install owncloud

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy  owncloud`

Answer (score 2):

run command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then try to install owncloud using

```
sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

or

if not work then add repository

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/community/xUbuntu_14.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list"
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud
```

or

install manually using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-mysql mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5-gd php5-json php5-curl php5-intl php5-mcrypt php5-imagick
```

then download owncloud and extract it to `/var/www/html/`

```
wget https://download.owncloud.org/community/owncloud-8.0.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf owncloud-8.0.0.tar.bz2 -C /var/www/html/
```

change ownership using

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/html/owncloud/
```

also create database for owncloud

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer but I find the solution before reading it. I uninstall curl with apt-get remove curl. Than I pass autoremove apt-get , I reinstall curl and after everyting was good with apt-get install owncloud.

Solved

Thanks a lot for the support

Comment: You should add this information as a comment rather than an answer, just out of curiosity did you not use sudo before the `apt-get install` command.From what you posted I feel @pl_rock was right in pointing that you should append sudo.